# Accurate computation of modified Bessel functions - Using netlib Fortran routines in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, fortran

I'm dealing with the problem of accurately calculating the modified Bessel function of zero-th order I0 in CUDA.

For a long time, I have been using a rational Chebyshev approximation according to the paper

J.M. Blair, "Rational Chebyshev approximations for the modified Bessel functions I_0(x) and I_1(x)", Math. Comput., vol. 28, n. 126, pp. 581-583, Apr. 1974.

which, as compared to the result provided by Matlab, gives an average error of the order of 1e-29. Unfortunately, this seemingly high accuracy is not anymore enough for a new application I'm working on.

Matlab uses the Fortran routines developed by D.E. Amos

Amos, D.E., "A Subroutine Package for Bessel Functions of a Complex Argument and Nonnegative Order," Sandia National Laboratory Report, SAND85-1018, May, 1985.

Amos, D.E., "A Portable Package for Bessel Functions of a Complex Argument and Nonnegative Order," Trans. Math. Software, 1986.

which are available for download from the [netlib/amos](http://www.netlib.org/amos/) website.

There are ways to use those Fortran routines in a C/C++ code by compiling them in a library file and then using a C/C++ wrapper (see for example [netlib_wrapping](http://difdop.polytechnique.fr/wiki/index.php/How_to_Bessel_Functions_in_C)). I'm wondering if there is any means to make device functions out of those Fortran routines to be then called by a CUDA kernel).

**MORE DETAILS ON THE PROBLEM**

I have two codes, one written in Matlab and one in CUDA. Both operate on three steps:

1) *Scaling by the modified Bessel function I0 and zero padding of data*;

2) *FFT*;

3) *Interpolation*.

I'm comparing both with an "exact" result: As output of step 3), Matlab gives a relative root mean square error of 1e-10 % while CUDA of 1e-2%, so I started investigating why.

The root mean square difference between the first step of the two codes, namely `100*sqrt(sum(abs(U_Matlab_step_1-U_CUDA_step_1).^2))/sqrt(sum(abs(U_Matlab_step_1).^2))`, is `0%` (`mean(mean(abs(U_Matlab-U_CUDA)))=6e-29` instead) so I would say it is good. Unfortunately, when I go to step 2, the error raises to `2e-4%`. Finally, if I feed step 2) of CUDA with the output of step 1) of Matlab, then the rms error of step 2) becomes `1e-14%`, which makes me think that a source of inaccuracy is due to the first step, namely, the calculation of the modified Bessel function.

**FOR INTERESTING DEVELOPMENTS OF THIS DISCUSSION**

Have a look at the [NVIDIA Developer Zone Forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/526734/cuda-programming-and-performance/accurate-computation-of-modified-bessel-functions-using-netlib-fortran-routines-in-cuda-/2/)

Comment: Is that 1e-29 error number a typo? Double precision floating point only has an epsilon value of about 1e-16. How/why are you comparing results to those sort of tolerances?

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for your prompt reply. I mean that, for a certain test case, I compare the outcome of my own implemented I0 with Matlab's by `mean(mean(abs(U_CUDA-U_Matlab)))` and I get `6.7036920e-029` as an answer. I need such a high accuracy as I'm implementing a 2D Non-Uniform FFT routine in CUDA. I have a Matlab routine which is much more accurate than the one I have written in CUDA, so I would like first to understand the reason of the loss of accuracy (and the calculation of the Bessel function is one of the reasons) as well as to improve the results provided by CUDA.

Comment: But what is the relative error?

Comment: Otherwise just rewrite the Fortran code to CUDA. A flowchart will be handy.

Comment: Your comparison methodology seems to assume that MATLAB delivers results accurate to better than 1e-29. How is that guaranteed? Does MATLAB use an arbitrary precision library internally? An accuracy of 1e-29 would require at least quadruple precision computation.

Comment: @VladimirF I tried to better explain the problem in the revised edition of my post. I would avoid rewriting a cumbersome Fortran code, as I believe that rewriting is error-prone. On the other side, Matlab implements the Bessel functions as the original Fortran routines accommodated in mex files, without rewriting them.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the note. I have tried to better explain my problem in the revised edition of my post. I'm aware that Matlab does not use arbitrary precision routines, but I have to explain the difference in the result between Matlab and CUDA. On the other side, if I would be able to use the same routines as Matlab uses for the modified Bessel function, then I could make a step forward to understand the source of inaccuracy.

Comment: The fact that your CUDA results differ from the Matlab results by an exceedingly small error amount do not give any indication of the actual error in either set of results. Only a comparison of both sets of results with a higher-precision reference would allow one to measure the amount of error in either set and to determine which set of results has the smaller error. Assuming you implemented exact same algorithm (and coefficients) in Matlab and CUDA, try compiling with -fmad=false to see if this makes the differences smaller (this will likely reduce performance and accuracy of the CUDA code).

Comment: I see you updated the question to mention that the final result is being compared to an "exact" result to determine the error. Could you be more specific as to what the "exact" reference is? A closed-form solution to the problem?

Comment: I'm implementing a Non-Uniform FFT, i.e., a fast way to calculate a Discrete Fourier Transform when the output grid is non-uniform. So, the reference is the Non-uniform DFT obtained by trivial summations.

Comment: But if that numerical DFT is calculated at the same precision as your bessel function based code, it is also subject to rounding and truncation error that will put its accuracy to be less than the epsilon value of the floating point type you used to do the computation. Without meaning to sound harsh - it seems your entire methodology for comparing results is based on a rather flawed understanding of how floating point arithmetic works and you may well be making a lot of difficult programming work for no good reason which ultimately won't yield results which are different to what you have now..

Comment: @talonmies Thank you for your notice. Please, take a look at my comment to Mikhail's answer. I made a mistake on the compute capability. Now Matlab and CUDA differ for about `1e-13` of normalized root mean square error. Anyway, I think I understand your point. If a quantity (Matlab) has an uncertainty eps, then, when used as a reference, I cannot infer about the accuracy of another quantity (CUDA) below eps. For example, if Matlab and CUDA differ for eps, then I cannot conclude which one is more accurate.

Comment: I think that my post raised two general issues. 1) If I have a Fortran legacy library, can I exploit it (without translating it) in a __device__ function? 2) If I have a routine, how can I infer about its accuracy? How to build up an "accurate" reference for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if this can be attributed to precision differences between floating point operations.

There are a few things to check out

1. Cuda 5 adds a few new trig functions that might better match the format of your computations. Also I think the CUDA math library since version 4 has some bessel functions, although I am not sure if this is true or how relevent they are to your problem.
2. Can you write a serial CPU version for testing? This will tell you if your precision problems are due to optimizations such as using 64bit vs 80bit representations of the number. With optimization turned off your computer will mostly deal with the 80bit representation (perhaps matlab does this), while with math optimizations turned on your compiler may deal with the less accurate 64bit representation. This releates to the difference between x87 and SSE.
3. Different compute capability hardware have slightly different precision. For example, compute 2.0 does FMA which is more accurate, and more closely resembles optimized x86.
4. Is there a physical reason to take Matlab as correct? It could be that your algorithm undershoots the results while Matlab overshoots. This kind of situation can occur if CUDA groups operations when Matlab doesn't.
5. If you must, must recreate Matlab results you can try to tune each step of your code by matching the output with different rounding tricks. See table.

Rounding table

```
addition       | x + y        | __dadd_[rn|rz|ru|rd](x, y)
multiplication | x * y        | __dmul_[rn|rz|ru|rd](x, y)
Fused-Mult-Add | fma(x, y, z) | __fma_[rn|rz|ru|rd](x, y, z)
reciprocal     | 1.0 / x      | __drcp_[rn|rz|ru|rd](x)
division       | x / y        | __ddiv_[rn|rz|ru|rd](x, y)
square root    | sqrt(x)      | __dsqrt_[rn|rz|ru|rd](x)

mode | interpretation
rn   | round to nearest, ties to even
rz   | round towards zero
ru   | round towards +∞
rd   | round towards -∞
```

From http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf

Comment: +1 for listing a whole bunch of relevant points. The most likely source of differences between CPU and GPU in double-precision computations is the default use of FMAs on the GPU. This can be turned off with the nvcc compiler flag -fmad=false, as I had mentioned above. As long as the CPU code uses SSE double precision results of individual operations should match with the GPU as both platforms implement IEEE-754 compliant basic math. Based on the updated question, I would say it is not clear that the differences in the final results are due to the small differences in Bessel function results.

Comment: @Mikhail The reason for the mismatch of the results I presented is due to a mistake on my side. I was compiling with compute capability 1.0 while running on a GPU with compute capability 2.0. Now things are much better. In other words, the normalized root mean square error between Matlab and CUDA is around `1e-13`. Point #3 of your Answer was driving me to find out the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @njuffa Thank you for having pointed out the fused multiply-add issue.

Comment: @njuffa In my revised post, I have quoted the recent developments of the discussion on the NVIDIA Developer Zone Forum.

Answer (score 0):

I found a introductory tech talk that answers your question. Here is the link to the [PDF](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/sc_2010/CUDA_Tutorial/SC10_Porting_Large_Fortran_Codebases_to_GPUs.pdf).
So yes it is possible, However I wasn't able to the aforementioned script to convert the legacy fortran code to CUDA C, maybe contact the developers directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From a very rough reading, it seems that they are porting Fortran codes by automatic converters, but not really making device functions out of them. I will have anyway a better reading.